# ethers.js swapExactETHForTokens and swapExactTokensForTokens on pancake swap

Tags: blockchain, web3js, ethers.js, binance-smart-chain

I'm having trouble with the following code and I can't buy on pancake swap.  I get the following errors depending on which function i call `swapExactETHForTokens` or `swapExactTokensForTokens`:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x18285588819662c93543dba5650d4471e62a504900b9a089f09dea4970698352
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x38ae19f6b677f072a82ac7c5528d445d3fc45288b1004f205d479edffee97b2f

Here is the code i'm using:

```
const ethers = require('ethers')
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/./../../.env' })

const config = {
  wbnb: '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c',
  safemoon: '0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3',
  pancakeSwapRouter: '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e',
  slippage: 12,
}

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  'wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443'
)

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(process.env.MNEMONIC)
const account = wallet.connect(provider)

const pancakeswap = new ethers.Contract(
  config.pancakeSwapRouter,
  [
    'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
    'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
    'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
  ],
  account
)

const wbnb = new ethers.Contract(
  config.wbnb,
  ['function approve(address spender, uint amount) public returns(bool)'],
  account
)

const buyToken = async () => {
  try {
    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20
    const tokenIn = config.wbnb
    const tokenOut = config.safemoon
    const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.001', 'ether')

    const amounts = await pancakeswap.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [
      tokenIn,
      tokenOut,
    ])
    const amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(`${config.slippage}`))

    console.log(`
Buying new token
tokenIn: ${amountIn} ${tokenIn} (WBNB)
tokenOut: ${amountOutMin} ${tokenOut}
    `)

    // const tx = await pancakeswap.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    //   amountIn,
    //   amountOutMin,
    //   [tokenIn, tokenOut],
    //   account.address,
    //   deadline,
    //   {
    //     gasPrice: provider.getGasPrice(),
    //     gasLimit: 100000,
    //   }
    // )

    const tx = await pancakeswap.swapExactETHForTokens(
      amountOutMin,
      [tokenIn, tokenOut],
      account.address,
      deadline,
      {
        gasPrice: provider.getGasPrice(),
        gasLimit: 100000,
      }
    )

    const receipt = await tx.wait()
    console.log('buyToken receipt')
    console.log(receipt)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

const approve = async () => {
  const valueToapprove = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.01', 'ether')
  const tx = await wbnb.approve(pancakeswap.address, valueToapprove, {
    gasPrice: provider.getGasPrice(),
    gasLimit: 100000,
  })
  console.log('Approving...')
  const receipt = await tx.wait()
  console.log('Approve receipt')
  console.log(receipt)
}

const main = async () => {
  await approve()
  await buyToken()
  process.exit()
}

main()
```

The approve works, but I can't figure out what's going wrong with the `swapExactTokensForTokens` or `swapExactETHForTokens`. Is calling approve required? Doesn't seem to help either way.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `swapExactETHForTokens` and try to add some `value` in the options.

```
const token = "Your token";
const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.0001", 'ether');

await approve(amountIn);


const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [
    addresses.WBNB,
    token
    
  ])

  const amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(12))

    const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(
    0,
    [addresses.WBNB, token],
    addresses.recipient,
    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, 
    {
        gasPrice: provider.getGasPrice(),
        gasLimit: 310000,
        value: amountIn
    }
);
```

Comment: non-payable method cannot override value

Comment: @starkm swapExactETHForTokens is payable https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexactethfortokens